# How to determine velocity and mass of asteroid 2011 CQ1

Tags: astrophysics, classical-mechanics

As you may have seen, a [small asteroid had a near miss with the earth a few days ago](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/badastronomy/2011/02/04/breaking-sofa-sized-asteroid-gives-us-a-close-shave/).

As a physics teacher teaching momentum, I think this could be an excellent problem for my students, however, I don't know how to determine the mass or velocity of this object. I could get a decent estimate of the mass simply by assuming its a spherical rock, but I still don't see how to determine the velocity. I can get the [orbital elements](http://www.minorplanetcenter.net/mpec/K11/K11C12.html):
[image: Orbital Elements of 2011 CQ1].

Is the 'V' term the magnitude of the velocity, and if so, what are those units? km/s? How could I get a heading for the asteroid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's better to read articles optimized for human readers, e.g.

> http://www.pagef30.com/2011/02/asteroid-2011-cq1-to-pass-by-earth-at.html

The relative velocity in the Earth's frame was 10 km/s when it was closest, 5471 km. Your webpage says that MOID (closest distance) was 0.0001 AU but it turned out to be 3 times closer at the end. A picture of the direction is included on the page I linked, too. The radius 1 meter wouldn't pose a problem if it hit us.

In the table, you have the ephemeris:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeris

Here, YYYY MM DD.## is the date (fourth of February 2011) followed by numbers 00-06 which are probably just labels (in the table I see above). It's separated by a space from the HH MM.MM time, changing from 8:20 to 8:21 or so (decimal point in minutes in between - about a minute was listed by you). What follows is R.A. or right ascension

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_ascension

(the entries are 14) which is the latitude on the Earth above which it occurs (where we see it), with the rotation of the Earth subtracted. Note that it is not moving much because the "horizontal" orbits of both bodies around the Sun are relatively synchronized. Then you get the declination

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declination

which is the ordinary Earth's latitude above which the object is located. It's changing between 37 and 43 (plus means North Hemisphere): the planes of orbits differ. From the changes of these two coordinates, you may deduce the angular velocity. The declination changed from 37.5 to 42.5 i.e. by 5 degrees = $pi/36$ radian. At distance of 5471 km I announced above, it's 477 kilometers. It took some time - the difference between 8:21.60 and 8:20.73 which is 0.87 minute i.e. 52 seconds, so you can see that the speed was about 10 km/s in your table

The table also includes Delta which I am not sure about now; distance from the Sun in AU called $r$ (which is obviously not too far from one), and elongation

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elongation_%28astronomy%29

which is the angle between the object and the Sun, as seen from the Earth. The distance from the Earth is not directly listed because it's not directly measured. One only knows the angle and the redshift. $V$ is not the velocity you want - which I calculated above.

Comment: I think mass can only be guessed from estimating both the diameter from visual and infrared brightness of the object, and density. Both of which are highly uncertain. It is way too small for its graviational effect on other objects to be measured. If it had had some interaction with the atmosphere, decelleration due to drag might also be used to constrain the mass. Something this small probably can't be detected unless it is near the earth. Velocity is messy, as you have the rotation and revolution of the earth to take account of.

Answer (score 0):

V is a measurement of visual magnitude, not velocity. Judging from the ephemeris data, it looks like you obtained information as the object was getting closer to earth. That would explain why the "v" was getting smaller. Smaller numbers in magnitude record brighter objects. Venus, for example is a "negative" number, while very distant, and dim objects have higher magnitude numbers.

I do not not know how to do this - however if your math is strong - then calculate the difference in RA (right ascension) and calculate the difference in declination (decl). These are the coordinates for 2011 CQ1.

Calculate the distance between each point. Record the time difference, as well, for each point calculated.

You can now determine the angular distance in arc seconds, or arc minutes.

As for velocity, in meters/second, or miles/hour - I've yet stumbled upon a clear cut example of how to do this.

Although, having imaged some known asteroids - and NASA has reported their diameter in kilometers - I have noted the time difference between frames - and measured the distance traveled in "asteroid" units (hehe).

Asteroid 1362 Griqua, for example, measures 28 km across. For arguments sake, it took 765 seconds to transverse 3.266 Griqua units. Which is 430 km/hr

In a separate measurement, I have recorded 26.13 "pixels" from one asteroid location, to the "last", over 765 seconds. Griqua is 8 pixels across, in my image. 26.13 / 8 = 3.266 Griqua units.

28 km * 3.266 = 91.5 km
91.5 km / 765 seconds = 430 km/hr

There was a jump in imaging between my first and second frame resulting in:

1,445 seconds elapsed between a distance of 48.88 pixel distance (center to center).

48.88 / 8 = 6.11 Griqua units.
6.11 * 28km = 171 km
171 km / 1,445 s = 426 km / hr

Cheers!

P.S. - way beyond my ability - if I were to re-image this minor planet as it passed by Jupiter, and observed its perturbations - one could derive its mass. Just a thought.

PPS - disappointing as it may seem - 430 km / hr is way too slow for this asteroid. For instance, the earth velocity is 30 km/s which is 108,000 km / hr, and a German orbital velocity study of Griqua was 16.49 km/s which is 59,364 km / hr.

The earth was moving "away" from Griqua (as Griqua was moving towards the earth during my measurement. If there is a difference in velocity of 108,000 - 59,364 = of around 50,000 km / hr makes a measurement of 430 km off by two decimal places.

Too much error in fact to disregard the answer as being close.

I will be looking at the field of view (FOV) of the telescope. And most likely the "size" of the asteroid was dilated and blurry, and needs to be "sharpened". If the visual was made smaller, the inherent velocity calculation would yield a much higher number. If this worlds out to 100x more, is unlikely, however.

A month later I decided to use actual mathematical calculations, and have verified them to be "precise".

Here ya go:
So that I do not get lost in the labyrinth of my own observations, I am noting here that Skynet 1362 Griqua observation # is 2335994, and the ID and location of image 0 and image 7 are:
ID: 19892011 RA/DEC: 00:27:52.198 / -24:59:39.468
ID 19892018 RA/DEC: 00:27:54.559 / -24:59:11.705

Both imaged on Prompt-5 telescope employing a Lum filter, and 4 seconds exposure.

The Universal Time (UT) stamp on my first image (image 0) is 01:30:06.154, and on my last (image 7) is 02:06:53.926. Whew! That was a mouthful !

We convert the hours, and minutes to seconds to make the math easier, multiplying minutes by 60 and hours by 3600.

01:30:06.154 = 5,406.154 s
02:06:53.926 = 7,613.926 s

Now take the difference, which will result in the time that passed between observations of image (0) and image (7) at the telescope: 7,613.926 - 5,406.154 = 2,207.772 s

The time elapsed was 2,207.772 seconds !

That was some pretty basic arithmetic. Now we have to delve a little deeper into the frugal realm of Pythagorus.

c (squared) = a(squared) + b(squared)

Or if you will permit me to flaunt my limited mathematical prowess:

c = the square root of ( (a*a) + (b*b) )

Hurray for right ascension and declination. They are the known coordinates of where we looked into the night sky. They happen to have a happy relationship as right angles to each other.

If you would, “one goes up” while “the other goes down”. No? How about, “right ascension or RA” is like horizontal direction, and “declination or DEC” is our vertical direction?

Still no?,…ummm..ok - my bad - I’ll try again - RA and DEC are two legs of a right triangle and we are going to solve for the hypotenuse. Yup, sorry. You asked teacher back in high school, “what am I going to do with geometry?” - well, here it is, my fellow budding amateur.

Take the DEC values, from above, and convert the coordinates to arc seconds. Multiply the minutes by 60 and the degrees by 3600. Sounds familiar, doesn’t it?

24:59:39.469 = 89,979.469 arc seconds
24:59:11.705 = 89,951.705 arc seconds

Now take the difference to find the change in DEC for our images:
89,979.469 - 89,951.705 = 27.764 arc sec

Take the RA values, from above, and convert the coordinates to arc seconds. Again, multiply the minutes by 60 and the hours by 3600.

00:27:54.559 = 1,674.559 seconds
00:27:52.198 = 1,672.198 seconds

Now, take the difference to find the change in RA for our images:
1674.559 - 1,672.198 = 2.361 sec

Our noteworthy author points out that our RA system is a grid of bent lines from earth bound pole to pole. And that the closer to the poles, the less space between the lines. And the closer to the equator, the more space between the lines. This curvature issue is solved by introducing the cosine into our math.

Another way to look at this, is that the circles that circumscribe the earth, as we vary the latitude, get smaller and smaller as we work our way to either North or South pole. That is what the cosine is there for.

First convert the DEC to degrees by dividing the arc seconds by 3600:
27.764 / 3600 = 0.00771222 degrees

change in RA(adjusted) = RA in seconds X 15 X cosine(DEC in degrees)

[note: the declination in degrees is NOT the difference, it is the actual DEC rounded off to the nearest degree]

= 2.361 X 15 X cosine(-25)

= 2.361 X 15 X cosine (-25)
= 2.361 X 15 X (0.906307787037)
= 32.096890277915355

Back to old Pythagorus:

take the square root of:
(32.096890277915355 * 32.096890277915355 + (27.764 * 27.764)

(1030.210365512537234729) + (770.8396960) = 1801.050061512537234729
…
= 42.438780160515184566614 arc seconds

Calculating the angular velocity of asteroid Griqua on December 27, 2017 is:

=42.438780160515184566614 / 2207.772 seconds
= 0.019222446955806661451732 arc seconds / second

( yes-sir-ree Bob! that be “arc seconds” per “second” ! )

Now onto the clear blue waters of Tangential Velocity of my beloved Griqua.

We need to know its angular velocity (already calculated as above), and its distance. Since I have no parallax data to provide us with (which would be used to calculate distance to the asteroid) we will peer into one of NASA’s databases to find our distance, on the evening of December 27, 2017, and use the starting time of observation for our starting point in time. However, as we look into a National solution, we find none. So we expand our search to include those found across the pond.

Plugging in our date time group, for our first and last observation into the ephemerides generator, located at the AstDyS-2 sponsored by ESA, and being observant to enter the telescopes’ location at Cerro Tololo, observatory code: 807, I get a delta (distance to asteroid from Earth) that varies from 1.9204 astronomical units (AU) to 1.9206 AU. Let’s use 1.9205, shall we? (our Sidereal Times editor will provide a link to ephemerides data, here).

Using a Google provided calculator, we convert 1.9205 AU, found here:
https://www.calculateme.com/Astronomy/AstronomicalUnits/ToKilometers.htm

1.9205 Astronomical Units =
287,302,710.67935 Kilometers

Tangential Velocity = (Angular velocity X distance) / 206,265
Vt = (0.019222446955806661451732 X 287302710) / 206,265

Vt = 26.775 km/s